# Как правильно реализовать принцип DDD?

Tags: ddd

Допустим, мы моделируем тендерные торги. Есть сущности менеджеры, тендеры, перевозчики и заявки. Менеджеры создают тендеры, а перевозчики подают заявки на тендеры. Как грамотно смоделировать эту ситуацию и где разместить методы - фабрики.

Вариант 1

```
Manager
+ startTender(params)

Transporter
+ applyBid(tenderId, price)
```

Вариант 2

```
Tender
+ startTender(params)
+ applyBid(transporterId, price)
```

Comment: DDD? Да его правильно реализовать в принципе нельзя:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ответа на этот вопрос следует рассмотреть 1) границы транзакционности подачи заявки и 2) к чьей сфере ответственности относятся связанные с этим действия.

Скажем, если у менеджера много тендеров, и нужно, чтобы перевозчики могли подавать заявки на каждый из них - границы транзакционности лучше определять тендером, а не менеджером. Поэтому подача заявки - это команда для агрегата "Тендер".

В то же время, решение об объявлении тендера принтмает менеджер, опираясь на имеющиеся в его распоряжении данные. Поэтому объявление тендера - команда агрегата "Менеджер".

Это не единственно возможный путь, но ход рассуждения примерно такой, как описано выше. Если появятся дополнительные детали - решение может и измениться.

Answer (score 0):

Голосую за вариант 2. **iTollu** верно сказал про границы транзакционности, но из описания задачи неочевиден тот факт, что необходимо иметь в коде такую прослойку как `менеджер` и о какой транзакционости идет речь применительно к менеджеру и перевозчику. Я ни разу не встречал реализацию в который оператор компьютера передавал бы сообщения своему виртуальному представлению. То же касается и перевозчика. То что такой объект в системе определенно необходим, это совсем не означает, что реальный залогиненый в системе субъект должен отправлять сообщения своему виртальному двойнику. Второй вариант это очень разумное решение с любой точки зрения.

Comment: Я так и не решил проблему "виртуального двойника". У Вон Вернона приводятся примеры когда предметная область содержит сущности Author, Creator, Moderator, Owner ведь они тоже отражаются на User

Comment: Виртальное представление выполняет роль объекта над которым совершаются операции, но никак не ретранслятора команд пользователя.